# Annoumous Function In VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, anonymous-methods

I have the following line of code in c#.

```
Check.ThatIsNotAnEmptyString(line1, () => { throw new InvalidAddressException("An address must have a street"); });
```

I am having difficulty converting it to vb.net.

I used the conversion tool 'www.developerfusion.com' but it produces the following piece of code.

```
Check.ThatIsNotAnEmptyString(line1, Function() Throw New InvalidAddressException("An address must have a street") End Function)
```

It complains on the word 'Throw' saying expression expected.

Can anyone tell me if converting this to vb.net is possible.

Comment: Side note: those tools seem to always fail on delegates, lambda expressions, events and the like...

Comment: They do, these converters invariably produce junk on the kind of statements where you need them the most.  The Sub keyword in a lambda expression isn't supported until VB10.  The fall-back is AddressOf with a little private method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `Sub`, since the function has no return value (like `void` in C#).

Also, since the function is on one line, you don't need to have a `End Sub/Function`, which is only needed on multiline functions (and was added in .Net 4.0).

---

So your code should read:

```
Check.ThatIsNotAnEmptyString(line1, Sub() Throw New InvalidAddressException("An address must have a street"))
```